# Return error if some "familiar" fields within an object are not adjacent

Tags: javascript

I have an object such as:

```
var dataObj = {
'hre': {groupID: 1},
'bla': {groupID: 1},
3: {groupID: 0},
4: {groupID: 2},
16: {groupID: 2},
6: {groupID: 2},
7: {groupID: 0},
64893: {groupID: 0},
9: {groupID: 1}
}
```

When the group is 0, it means that the field doesn't pertain to any group.

Fields of the same group must be adjacent. Else it should throw an error.

So for instance the object above would throw an error because fields of group 1 are not adjacent.

Looking for an efficient way of getting this done (or any way for that matter, because I haven't found one after some time).

```
var error = false;
var previousGroupID = null;
var thisGroupID = null;
var previousFieldGroupID = null;

for (index in dataArray) {
    if (dataObj[index]['groupID'] > 0) {
        thisGroupID = dataObj[index]['groupID'];
        if (previousFieldGroupID == 0 && thisGroupID ==  previousGroupID) {
            error = true;
        }
    }
    previousFieldGroupID = dataObj[index]['groupID'];
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zq2w7w9t/1/

Comment: This is not possible, since properties in JS objects are not guaranteed to have any specific order.

Comment: considering your object keys are numbers, perhaps you mean it to be an array?

Comment: My fields are always from 1 to 9. We can loop and be assured that the order is correct.

Comment: We can loop, but we can't be sure the order is correct.

Comment: @Teemu How come? Every time I loop, I see the index going from 1 to 9.

Comment: @amenadiel I gave this object as example to make it simpler, but sometimes the keys are strings and the index is actually given as a property along other properties.

Comment: That depends on the implementation, please check [standard](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4). "The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (...) is not specified"

Comment: Can we achieve something with what I got here?

Comment: Using arrays as amenadiel has suggested.

Comment: My keys aren't always numbers

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can use an array of objects, like `[{1: {groupID: 1}}, {2: {groupID: 2}} ...]`.

Comment: Fields in an object have no order - they are not adjacent or non-adjacent, they simply exist (or not). You need some kind of ordered list of objects, and in javascript that's probably most easily accomplished with an array.

Comment: Shall the algorithm return error for this? { 1: {groupID: 1}, 2: {groupID: 0}, 3: {groupID: 1} }, so does the item with 0 groupID break the group with ID 1?

Comment: Yes -- groups should be adjacent in any case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JavaScript engine retains ordering of members (most of them does, but *they don't have to*, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)):

```
function hasError(dataObj) {
  var error = false;
  var previousGroupID = -1;
  var thisGroupID = -1;
  var seenGroups = new Set();

  for (index in dataArray) {
    thisGroupID = dataObj[index].groupID;
    if (previousGroupID !== thisGroupID) {
      if (seenGroups.has(thisGroupID)) {
        if (thisGroupID !== 0) error = true;
      } else {
        seenGroups.add(thisGroupID);
      }
    }
    previousGroupID = thisGroupID;
  }
  return error;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is [guaranteed to retain entry ordering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```
function hasError(dataMap) {
  var error = false;
  var previousGroupID = -1;
  var thisGroupID = -1;
  var seenGroups = new Set();
  var thisGroup = null;
  for (thisGroup of dataMap.values()) {
    thisGroupID = thisGroup.groupID;
    if (previousGroupID !== thisGroupID) {
      if (seenGroups.has(thisGroupID)) {
        if (thisGroupID !== 0) error = true;
      } else {
        seenGroups.add(thisGroupID);
      }
    }
    previousGroupID = thisGroupID;
  }
  return error;
}

var m = new Map();
m.set('hre', { groupID: 1 });
m.set('bla', { groupID: 1 });
m.set(3, { groupID: 0 });
m.set(4, { groupID: 2 });
m.set(5, { groupID: 0 });
m.set(1, { groupID: 1 });
console.log(hasError(m));
```

Or you can break it down into separate functions:

```
function listHasError(list) {
  var error = false;
  var previousGroupID = -1;
  var thisGroupID = -1;
  var seenGroups = new Set();
  var thisGroup = null;
  list.forEach(function(thisGroupID) {
    if (previousGroupID !== thisGroupID) {
      if (seenGroups.has(thisGroupID)) {
        if (thisGroupID !== 0) error = true;
      } else {
        seenGroups.add(thisGroupID);
      }
    }
    previousGroupID = thisGroupID;
  });
  return error;
}
function extractGroupsFromMap(dataMap) {
  var res = [];
  for (thisGroup of dataMap.values()) {
    res.push(thisGroup.groupID);
  }
  return res;
}
function extractGroupsFromObj(dataObj) {
  var res = [];
  for (index in dataObj) {
    res.push(dataObj[index].groupID);
  }
  return res;
}

var dataObj = {
  'hre': {groupID: 1},
  'bla': {groupID: 1},
  3: {groupID: 0},
  4: {groupID: 2},
  16: {groupID: 2},
  6: {groupID: 2},
  7: {groupID: 0},
  64893: {groupID: 0},
  9: {groupID: 1}
};
console.log(listHasError(extractGroupsFromObj(dataObj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming that:

- Your object has arbitrary keys
- Each value has a numerical index attribute and a groupId
- having non consecutive elements with group 0 isn't an error
- index attributes are exclusive and consecutive

Then let's say your object looks like:

```
var    yourObject = {
    'a1': {     index: 1,       groupId: 1  },
    'b2': {     index: 2,       groupId: 1  },
    'c3': {     index: 3,       groupId: 0  },
    'd4': {     index: 4,       groupId: 5  },
    'e5': {     index: 5,       groupId: 5  },
    'g6': {     index: 6,       groupId: 5  },
    'h7': {     index: 7,       groupId: 'A'},
    'i8': {     index: 8,       groupId: 0  },
    'j9': {     index: 9,       groupId: 'A'}
    };
```

(please note I intentionally used non consecutive nor exclusively numerical group ids).

Then I would group your object using:

```
var groups={};
Object.keys(yourObject)
    .forEach(function (key) {
        var thevalue = yourObject[key],
            groupId = thevalue.groupId;

        groups[groupId] = groups[groupId] || [];

        groups[groupId].push(thevalue.index);
});
```

at this point, `groups` is an object whose keys are 0,1,5 and 'A', and their values are the value of the `index` atribute (which we said was consecutive and exclusive).

```
{
    0: [3,8],
    1: [1,2],
    5: [4,5,6],
    'A':[7,9]
}
```

I will iterate on `groups`, and for every group I'll skip the verification if it has a single element or it's group zero.

If it has more than 1 element, and it isn't group zero, then I'll sort its elements and iterate on them. Since indexes are consecutive, each of these sorted arrays must not have items with difference > 1 among them

```
var hasError = false;

Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (groupId) {
    if (groupId !== 0 && groups[groupId] && groups[groupId].length > 1) {

        var sortedElements = groups[groupId].sort(function (a, b) {
            return a > b;
        });
        console.log('Group ' + groupId, sortedElements);

        for (var index = 1; index < sortedElements.length; index++) {
            if ((sortedElements[index] - sortedElements[index - 1]) > 1) {
                hasError = true;
                console.warn('Error detected');
            }
        }
    }
});
```